# Load table from Oracle to Hive, date and timestamp convert to string

Tags: sqoop2, sqoop

I have noticed this in the Sqoop manual:

> 24.5. Schema Definition in Hive
>
> Hive users will note that there is not a one-to-one mapping between SQL types and Hive types. In general, SQL types that do not have a direct mapping (for example, DATE, TIME, and TIMESTAMP) will be coerced to STRING in Hive. The NUMERIC and DECIMAL SQL types will be coerced to DOUBLE. In these cases, Sqoop will emit a warning in its log messages informing you of the loss of precision.

And I know Sqoop can specify the column - type mapping using

- `--map-column-java`
- `--map-column-hive`

But my case is I need a general type to type mapping, from RDBMS type to HIVE type mapping which require date or datetime convert to a date or timestamp.

Is there a solution exist?

Comment: The format of date and timestamp **is not same** in hive and in RDBMS databases. So you can't make a generic solution for that. You have to convert it manually using `--map-column-hive` for each RDBMS

Comment: Can you make it more details about the difference between date and timestamp in Hive and in RDBMS and the reason why there is no generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop + ORC + hcatalog  helps you in correct mapping. 
Sqoop + parquet it will convert date into String

```
mysqlHostname=ip-172-31-2-124.us-west-2.compute.internal                          
mysqlDBName=employees                                                             
mysqlUsername=hive                                                                


sqoop import \
      --connect jdbc:mysql://$mysqlHostname/$mysqlDBName \
      --table salaries \
      --username $mysqlUsername \
      -P \
      --hcatalog-table orc_salaries \
      --create-hcatalog-table \
      --map-column-hive  from_date=date,to_date=date\
      --hcatalog-storage-stanza 'stored as orcfile tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB")'
```